# Implementing custom SSRS security within the report logic, in addition to ReportServer

Tags: security, reporting-services, report, logic, userid

SSRS Version 2008 (Not R2)

Hi all.
I am trying to implement custom security within a report being used for call center managers and agents.  Here are my requirements:

- Agents can see their own stats and no one else's stats.
- Managers can see anyone's stats

I have a report that shows basic call center stats like # of dropped calls, on hold time, etc.  The report has two parameters.  One for @Date and one for @AgentID.  We want to make sure the managers can view this report for any agent and the agents can see their stats and only their stats.  I have tried a few techniques and would like to accomplish this within the report logic (stored procedure).  My latest attempt involved capturing the current user's login (SELECT CURRENT_USER) and then bumping that up against a WHERE clause in the report's main SELECT statement.  This seems to work fine in SQL/SSMS but does not seem to catch on when deployed as an SSRS report.

```
-- Sample user table
SELECT DISTINCT
     ManagerID
    ,ManagerName
    ,LoginID
    ,'Manager' AS LEVEL
INTO #user_SOURCE
From dbo.AgentTable
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
     AgentID
    ,AgentName
    ,LoginID
    ,'Agent'
From dbo.AgentTable
UNION
SELECT
     1
    ,'My Name'
    ,'mylogin'
    ,'Tester'
```

-- Then i have my simple SELECT statement that is inside a stored procedure and called by the report.

```
select top 1000 * 
from dbo.CallCenterReportTable
where CURRENT_USER IN 
        (
        SELECT
        LoginID
        FROM #user_SOURCE
        )
```

The interesting thing is that i can do testing fine in SSMS, and i can even test it successfully in my local BIDS, but it only works in BIDS if i slightly adjust anything inside the report like page size, etc.  Anything that would require a re-save of the RDL seems to make the security function as it should when viewing locally.  That being said, the security will not work once deployed to the SSRS server.  Even if I change the RDL slightly and redeploy, it does not work.

My last resort would be to create two reports that are almost identical.  One would restrict use to only call center managers by AD role.  The other would be open to agents and would utilize the USERID internal parameter in SSRS (WHERE USERID=@AgentID).  I would really like to avoid having two reports if at all possible.

Comment: You need to pass the UserID from Report to the stored procedure. In `Built-in Fields` you will see `User ID`.

Comment: the builtin SSRS UserID parameter ended up being the solution.  i was thinking that i wouldn't be able to use it for the managers but in in the report proc i created a temp table containing all managers' logins, then the login of the agent's stats being requested.  if the agent requesting the stats matches the agent who's stats are being requested, then the agent can see it.  the managers can still see everything.  thanks for the suggestion t_m!  i had considered it before but had to rethink it after your response.